# EditText without auto-correction, etc

Tags: android

My EditText needs to accept input consisting of partial words, names, etc. At least on my HTC Desire, this is difficult since the keyboard wants to suggest and/or correct some entries (e.g., changes "gor" to "for"). I tried setting textNoSuggestions on the view, but that doesn't fix it.

Any simple solution to this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can do this from the code. Set the input type of the EditText like below:

```
txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
txtEmail.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

For a list of all the available input type options see
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Answer (score 71):

Try this:

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: Doesn't work on a Nexus 5 with the last version of the Google keyboard, but it works with `textVisiblePassword`.

Answer (score 38):

The other suggestions are correct, but [SwiftKey](http://www.swiftkey.net/en/) has decided [it will ignore the inputtype values "in response to user requests"](http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116693-2-bug-reports/suggestions/3684116-swiftkey-insist-on-making-prediction-even-for-edit). While I agree this is a bad idea since it contradicts the Google guidelines and developers usually have a good reason for disabling auto-correction (like username fields, family names and so on), it still is the most used keyboard application for Android devices, so this can be a big problem.

The workaround is to use either

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

or

```
.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Then be prepared to have a problem with typeface monospace. :)

Comment: Thank you for this!  I confirm it works with Swiftkey, where the other solutions (textNoSuggestions and/or textFilter) did not.

Comment: @LéonPelletier: Please explain.

Comment: Before API 16, you need to apply a transformation. On API 16+, you can set the font. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406534/password-hint-font-in-android Very old bug. Impact everything I've coded so far on Android when designing the Login screen.

Comment: Swiftkey resists that and still capitalizes, but at least turns off suggestions in Swiftkey and also in Google keyboard... :(

Comment: @FerranMaylinch I am using Swiftkey and it *doesn't resist* `inputType="textVisiblePassword`, i.e. will not show prediction, if that's what you meant. Maybe you are using it together with other values.

Comment: @jj_ Suggestions are turned off, yes. What it doesn't turn off is capitalization each time I start a new line. I will end up suggesting the user to switch to the stock keyboard while using my app because it's a coding app and those caps are really annoying. I see that other apps like DroidEdit suffer from the same issue.

Comment: @FerranMaylinch ah ok I see, thanks for making it clear.

Comment: for swift key i use    `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapSentences"`

Answer (score 4):

Try this if you want a **multi-line** EditText without displaying the underlines (auto correct):

```
    myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
       InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Here's XML for that: `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"`.