# Android EditText With Suggestions, but Without AutoCorrect

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

Is there a way I can get android Edit Text to **show suggestions** when the user type the word, but **do not auto-correct** the value. Autocorrect shall be shown only if user clicks on the suggestion.

I've checked the following answers...
[EditText without auto-correction, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799840/edittext-without-auto-correction-etc)
, but it doesn't show suggestions at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for [Providing Auto-complete Suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html) for suggesting data.

And if you want to stop auto-correcting then try to add this line into your EditText.

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

Hope it will help you.