# Can auto-correction of user's keyboard be disabled through my android application?

Tags: android, input, keyboard, user-input, android-inputtype

I am making an android application that checks user's spelling skills, so it is mandatory not to get any help from his keyboard's auto-correction feature.

Can I disable it (auto-correction / auto-completion) through my application or I should create my own custom keyboard?

[Android Official Documentation - Input Type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText without auto-correction, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799840/edittext-without-auto-correction-etc)

Comment: You can see the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3799840/2661303 and in many other discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Ref: [Android Dev Site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish the above programmatically:

```
view_id.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```