# change font for editText hint

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to change the font for the hint displayed in the `EditText` field? I want to set the font in the xml itself.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716959/setting-typeface-of-hint-in-textedit

Comment: As pointed out, this is a duplicate.  You can change the hint color, but not the typeface.

Comment: you can check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40695930/3578171) hope it works.

Answer (score 28):

You can change it with a SpannableString and a Custom TypefaceSpan.

First, create a Custom TypefaceSpan class:

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {
    private final Typeface mNewType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(Typeface type) {
        super("");
        mNewType = type;
    }

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        mNewType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, mNewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, mNewType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Then just set the TypefaceSpan to a SpannableString:

```
TypefaceSpan typefaceSpan = new CustomTypefaceSpan(typeface);
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(hintText);

spannableString.setSpan(typefaceSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

And finally just set the hint of your EditText:

```
mEditText.setHint(spannableString);
```

Comment: This is a correct answer for me, thanks @francisco_ssb. It works perfectly.

Comment: Awesome use of a Span! In my case, I didn't need a true "custom Typeface" but just a system font and appearance that was different than the regular text. I used a TextAppearanceSpan on the hint and it worked like a charm.

Comment: but, this approach doesn't float the current hint. Any suggestion how to make it float to the above field?

@LisaWray

Comment: @mochadwi the "floating" you're thinking of is probably an effect of TextInputLayout, a Material design wrapper for EditText. I'm on mobile right now, but just Google :)

Comment: I see, so, with this code, plus hint on TextInputLayout, should do the trick? *cmiiw

@LisaWray

Answer (score 7):

I haven't find out any useful way to change hint font in XML.But you can achieve like this:

```
mEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.length()== 0) {
            //mEt.setTypeFace(normalFont);
        }else{
           // mEt.setTypeFace(hintFont);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Simple solution, as it should be

Comment: @Darius lol actually looks like there is no better...

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple way to do it. I just did in my App and it worked.
The Key is set Facetype of your TextInputLayout too along with EditText.

```
mEmailView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), getString(R.string.app_font)));
((TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.tilEmail)).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), getString(R.string.app_font)));
```

Answer (score 3):

@francisco_ssb's answer is correct. However, I will provide an alternative solution which helps to change not only a hint's font, but also its size and style. I hope this solution will be helpful.

**1) Create a custom `Hint` object:**

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

public class CustomHint extends SpannableString
{
    public CustomHint(final CharSequence source, final int style)
    {
        this(null, source, style, null);
    }

    public CustomHint(final CharSequence source, final Float size)
    {
        this(null, source, size);
    }

    public CustomHint(final CharSequence source, final int style, final Float size)
    {
        this(null, source, style, size);
    }

    public CustomHint(final Typeface typeface, final CharSequence source, final int style)
    {
        this(typeface, source, style, null);
    }

    public CustomHint(final Typeface typeface, final CharSequence source, final Float size)
    {
        this(typeface, source, null, size);
    }

    public CustomHint(final Typeface typeface, final CharSequence source, final Integer style, final Float size)
    {
        super(source);

        MetricAffectingSpan typefaceSpan = new CustomMetricAffectingSpan(typeface, style, size);
        setSpan(typefaceSpan, 0, source.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

**2) Create custom `MetricAffectingSpan` object:**

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

public class CustomMetricAffectingSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan
{
    private final Typeface _typeface;
    private final Float    _newSize;
    private final Integer  _newStyle;

    public CustomMetricAffectingSpan(Float size)
    {
        this(null, null, size);
    }

    public CustomMetricAffectingSpan(Float size, Integer style)
    {
        this(null, style, size);
    }

    public CustomMetricAffectingSpan(Typeface type, Integer style, Float size)
    {
        this._typeface = type;
        this._newStyle = style;
        this._newSize = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
    {
        applyNewSize(ds);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint)
    {
        applyNewSize(paint);
    }

    private void applyNewSize(TextPaint paint)
    {
        if (this._newStyle != null)
            paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(this._typeface, this._newStyle));
        else
            paint.setTypeface(this._typeface);

        if (this._newSize != null)
            paint.setTextSize(this._newSize);
    }
}
```

**3) Use:**

```
Typeface newTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "AguafinaScript-Regular.ttf");
CustomHint customHint = new CustomHint(newTypeface, "Enter some text", Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC, 60f);
        //        CustomHint customHint = new CustomHint(newTypeface, "Enter some text", Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        //        CustomHint customHint = new CustomHint(newTypeface, "Enter some text", 60f);
        //        CustomHint customHint = new CustomHint("Enter some text", Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC, 60f);
        //        CustomHint customHint = new CustomHint("Enter some text", Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        //        CustomHint customHint = new CustomHint("Enter some text", 60f);

customEditText.setHint(customHint);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible in XML -

Text and hint can only have the same font in XML.

Answer (score 2):

I can change the hint font by use this [library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) .

After compiling the library you must create a class of applications and  the class definition  following command:

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                  .setDefaultFontPath("font.ttf")
                  .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                  .build()
          );
```

After each activity you want Override it with the following command:

```
@Override
      protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
          super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
      }
```

Comment: After compiling the library you must create a class of applications and  the class definition  following command:
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("font.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build()
        );
After each activity you want Override it with the following command:

@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

Comment: @johnny5, this answer helped me as I was using the Calligraphy library that this answer refers to. HOSHYAR Ahmadpour also explained the answer. Thank you for the answer HOSHYAR Ahmadpour.

Comment: @Sakiboy yeah that's good, I was in the review queues assuring that future people would be able to use this answer,  I upvoted him after he fixed his answer

Answer (score 1):

Take the approach of using a text input layout and placing a text input edit text inside

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_Til">

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:id="@+id/editText"/>

 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

On the Fragment/Activity , Set the font you want for the hint onto the TextInputLayout(**text_input_layout_Til**)
Then set the font on the edit text(**editText**) as well / 
If you do this , The text the user will input and the hint will have different fonts

Answer (score 0):

With Android 8.0 (API level 26) comes a new feature that gives a possibility to change font in xml for the hint displayed in the EditText. Guide based on [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml).

Steps:

**1)** Create a new resource directory: right-click the **res** folder and go to **New -> Android resource directory**.

**2)** Set name of resource directory as **font**.

**3)** In the **Resource type list**, select **font**,  and then click OK.

**4)** Add your custom font(e.g. my_font.ttf) in the **font** folder.

**5)** In the layout XML, set the **fontFamily** attribute to the font file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"/>
```

... or if you want to do it programmatically:

```
val typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.my_font)
edit_text.typeface = typeface
```

To use the Fonts in XML feature on devices running Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher, use the Support Library 26:

> Note: When you declare font families in XML layout through the support library, use the app namespace to ensure your fonts load.

**1)** In **font** directory create **custom_font.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/my_font"/>
</font-family>
```

**2)** Set the **fontFamily** attribute:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font"/>
```

... or if you want to do it programmatically:

```
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.custom_font)
edit_text.typeface = typeface
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

```
            nomeEditText.setText("New Text") //changes the text
            nomeEditText.isEnabled = false //disables editable
            nomeEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")) //changes background
            nomeEditText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#737373")) //changes color text
            nomeEditText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,28f) //changes text size
            nomeEditText.typeface = Typeface.create("@font/roboto", Typeface.BOLD) //changes font familly
            nomeEditText.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL //centralize
```

Answer (score -3):

use this code:

```
edittext.setAccentTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: This is not available for EditText.