# Password hint font is different than other edittext fields

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-typeface

```
EditText password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Typeface typeface = TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/calibri.ttf");
        password.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
```

And this is the XML layout for the `TextInputLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inpPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin_small">

    <android.support.design.widget.EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/set_pass"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLength="@integer/pass_max"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I am trying to use this code but my password hint font style is different than which I had set.

Comment: You are Using   `android:inputType="textPassword"` so that it's showing different font.remove this line `android:inputType="textPassword"` check it once.

Comment: Please explain from what is it different and provide relevant code

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35322532/6891637)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change font for editText hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251990/change-font-for-edittext-hint)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

addding to this, It works when the iandroid:inputType=" textPassword" is removed and adding app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inpPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin_small"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/set_pass"
                android:maxLength="@integer/pass_max"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



EditText password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    password.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
<Edittext
            android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Set `android:inputType="text"` in your edittext xml.

Set `edtPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());` in java file.

Works for me in custom font for edittext.

Answer (score 3):

Hey if someone is using kotlin I hope this code helps you, it is working for me. I'm using
`com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` 
and `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText`

in kotlin:

```
// find the view
val etPassword = view.findViewById<AppCompatEditText>(R.id.etPassword)

// set the typeface to your choice
etPassword.typeface = Typeface.SANS_SERIF

// the set its transformationMethod to PasswordTransformationMethod
etPassword.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod()
```

this is my xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am also face this problem.

You have to try this way, you will got solution.

XML code

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:id="@+id/password_text"/>
```

Java Code

```
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);
    password.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Hope this will helps you...

Comment: Yes this is good but it doesnot work fully , only works on removing android:inputType:"textPassword"

Answer (score 2):

use `android:fontFamily="sans-serif"`

Answer (score 0):

I observed that the font style of my Edittext was different when the input type was textPassword. Fixed this by using the fontFamily attribute.

Below is the code which I used in my layout:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="My Password hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```