# How to set custom font for Android SearchView hint text?

Tags: android, searchview

I've seen numerous questions and answers on how to change the text colour of a SearchView's hint text, but is it also possible to change the font for the hint text (preferably, in xml)?

I've searched the web and looked in the [SearchView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView) and there doesn't seem to be anything relating to this.

Comment: See answer of francisco_ssb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35322532/7749832)