# Android EditText on longPress: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=491

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have this strange behavior I cannot explain.
My layout is quite simple: An EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I try to longPress it (to paste some text) I got an imediate Force Close and this error:

```
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:2995)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2280)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2968)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2968)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3189)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3416)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:3652)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:870)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:7973)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:17140)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    ... 25 more
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=491
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:64)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:720)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:124)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:800)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:450)
05-08 16:56:16.838: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    ... 28 more
```

I have really no clue what's happening, and I would be pleased to get some help!

Just to be clear, I have nothing in my Activity related to a listener on this EditText:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_pro);

    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like an add-in is malfunctioning. Are you doing this in an Emulator or an actual phone?

Comment: On a Sony Xperia Z, I will try on the emulator now.

Comment: Looks like the system is trying to create a PopupWindow containing a TextView. Then it crashes when applying the theme. Do you use a custom theme? Anything unusual going on there?

Comment: I guess that's the copy/paste popupWindow, I use Theme.DeviceDefault, I will try with other theme...

Comment: Indeed,  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item> will make the EditText crash. Thank for your help, I would never have find by myself.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just remove this line from your custom style

This single line:

```
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
```

Will make the EditText crash when long pressing it.

The Android copy/paste popup was the root cause of the error.

Comment: no add-in? That's disappointing, in a way. And did it crash in the Emulator as well?

Comment: I had the same error and removing the fontFamily tag from the theme-style tag fixed it. However, correct me if I'm wrong, I assume setting the fontFamily in the theme has no affect on child elements. You have to create extra styles for TextViews,EditTexts, Buttons etc.

Comment: Applying the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app is a workaround for this.

But also add 

        `<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditText</item>`

and:
`<style name="EditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">`
`<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>`
`</style>`

Answer (score 1):

this link solved my issue, although the auto-complete in xml files was not working, but the code in this example is correct, i declared all in the same styles file and it worked :

https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/issues/162

and that's what was said in it :

Seems to be an error in styles, verify if you have

```
<item name="android:fontFamily"></item>
```

in your application theme, not in the themes view, in application theme.
The same error happened to me until i removed this line of my style.xml, if you have that line, remove them, if you need this property, you can stylize textviews and buttons with:

```
<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
</style>
```

And in your app theme, use:

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
```

Comment: Worked perfect for me!  Good find.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem ;

but the cause of it is that i use ContextThemeWrapper;

here is how we get LayoutInflater from ContextThemeWrapper

```
@Override 
public Object getSystemService(String name) {
    if (LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
        if (mInflater == null) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mBase).cloneInContext(this);
        }
        return mInflater;
    }
    return mBase.getSystemService(name);
}
```

from the code block above, we can see that it handle LayoutInflater specially, which is the source of the problem.

my solution is : override this method as follow

```
@Override
public Object getSystemService(String name){
    return getBaseContext().getSystemService(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem when using `<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>` in `style.xml`

It **CRASH** on

- Samsung S4 (SC-04E) (5.0.1)
- Samsung Galaxy Node 5 (5.1.1)

It **NOT CRASH** on

- **Samsung** S7 Edge (SM-G935F) (7.0)
- Xiaomi A2 (8.0.1)
- Pixel XL (8.1.0)
- Sony Xperia Z5 Au (SOV32) (6.0)
- Arrow NX (F-04G) (6.0.1)
- Kyocera (S2) (7.0)

At first, I think this problem will only happened on `Samsung` but **Samsung S7** don't crash.

Then I think the API may cause this problem because current crash device have API < 6.0. However I am not sure about it because I don't have much device for testing

> Summary: It will crash in some device

**TO FIX THIS PROBLEM**
First, remove `sans-serif`
Then download `Roboto` font from https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/apache/roboto then add to project following https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

**Why** `Roboto` font?
You are facing this problem when using `sans-serif` font right?
`sans-serif` in Android is `Roboto` font (see here [Android default font](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39536066/5381331))

If you know some device which will crash, please edit my answer, it may help for testing.
Hope it help