# Android app crashes on Long click on the Edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, samsung-mobile, android-8.0-oreo

I am checking a very strange bug reported on Crashlytics. Basically the logs shows that whenever the user clicks on one of the edit text in the app, it crashes.

```
Crashed: main
   at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1142)
   at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:12675)
   at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:6934)
   at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:26034)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

It happens 100% on Samsung with Android 8.0.0, which has the follow distribution

- Samsung S9+ (48%)
- Samsung S8+ (33%)
- Samsung S8 (7%)
- Samsung S8+ (5%)
- Samsung S9 (2%)

Has anyone faced similar issues?

Comment: Does this help you, https://stackoverflow.com/q/16444061/6891563

Comment: No man its working perfect with the Samsung S8.

Comment: Thanks @Khemraj I will take a look into it.

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal It happens on some of the devices. I have checked it on my Samsung Galaxy S8 and it works fine. I guess there are some fine configuration issue that I am not aware about.

Comment: Have you created the custom EditText and than after you're trying to perform the onLongClick?

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal Yeah. I am not saying that you are lier. :) it is just that kind of phantom issue that does not happens always. As Khemraj pointed out, it might well related with the font-family. I need to narrow down the cases when we use that font and try to reproduce the error. I will keep you updated.

Comment: No friend i am just trying to help you if possible in another way.

Comment: Its related to the font-family on your component, e.g a TextField or EditText.  Remove sans-serif should fix it on those devices.