# Error trying to change password hint font

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to follow the advice from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406534/password-hint-font-in-android):

But when I run this code, my program crashes. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Change the font for the password hint to match that of the
     * user name field */
    EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    pw.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);    //<---Crashes on this line
    pw.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Here is the XML for this object:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

And finally, here is the LogCat output where I can see the error:

> 05-09 00:30:21.408: E/Trace(16987): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2) 05-09 00:30:21.918: D/AndroidRuntime(16987):
>   Shutting down VM 05-09 00:30:21.918: W/dalvikvm(16987): threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 05-09
>   00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 05-09
>   00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mobilenicity.gen_co_event_marketing_app/com.mobilenicity.gen_co_event_marketing_app.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 05-09 00:30:21.978:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   05-09 00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   05-09 00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 05-09
>   00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   05-09 00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-09
>   00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 05-09 00:30:21.978:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 05-09
>   00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-09
>   00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-09 00:30:21.978:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   05-09 00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 05-09
>   00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-09 00:30:21.978:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16987): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-09 00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   com.mobilenicity.gen_co_event_marketing_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
>   05-09 00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 05-09
>   00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   05-09 00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   05-09 00:30:21.978: E/AndroidRuntime(16987):  ... 11 more

Can't figure out what is going wrong. Can anybody see it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the call of `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Call it **just after** `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

---

When you're doing `EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);`, `findViewById` "can't retrieve" the `EditText` that you have defined in your `layout` (because you call `setContentView` after) so `findViewById` returns null and when you're doing `pw.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);` it throws a `NPE` because pw is `null`.