# android setting password type with custom font

Tags: java, android, textview

I have used this code to set textType = password.

`mInputText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);`

I however it ruins my custom font for the editText.

How can I combine them both?

Comment: Go to this for better achievement [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406534/password-hint-font-in-android?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406534/password-hint-font-in-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set the type after setting the flags

```
public void setPasswordTextType() {
    mInputText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    mInputText.setTypeface(MY_TYPE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use   `android:inputType="textPassword"` Ex:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:password="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" >

    </EditText>
```