# Can't use custom font in password hint Android Studio

Tags: android, fonts, passwords

I am trying to use a custom font in a password hint field in Android Studio.

After I set the Edit Text as `inputType="textPassword"` in XML, the font changes to a different from the one I've chosen. All the other Edit Texts have the correct custom font.

I've tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3444882/11440760) solution in java code (replaced **Typeface.DEFAULT** with **R.font.my_font**) but nothing happened

```java
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password_text);
    password.setTypeface(R.font.my_font);
    password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52176331/11440760) solution with no success

```java
    Typeface cache = edtPassword.getTypeface();
    edtPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    edtPassword.setTypeface(cache);
```

Any ideas on what to try or what might be missing in these solutions?

PS: I'm using **montserrat_regular** font

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because you are passing the id of the font in
password.setTypeface(R.font.my_font)  not the TypeFace Object. You need to pass **TypeFace** object in setTypeFace() method , so to make TypeFace object from your font resource Id just add the code

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.my_font);
password.setTypeface(typeface);
```

I think this should work.